# LINQ: How to Append List of Elements Into Another List

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following class

```
public class Element
{
  public List<int> Ints
  {
     get;private set;
  }
}
```

Given a `List<Element>`, how to find a list of all the `Ints` inside the `List<Element>` using LINQ?

I can use the following code

```
public static List<int> FindInts(List<Element> elements)
{
 var ints = new List<int>();
 foreach(var element in elements)
 {
  ints.AddRange(element.Ints);
 }
 return ints;
 }
}
```

But it is so ugly and long winded that I want to vomit every time I write it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
return (from el in elements
        from i in el.Ints
        select i).ToList();
```

or maybe just:

```
return new List<int>(elements.SelectMany(el => el.Ints));
```

btw, you'll probably want to initialise the list:

```
public Element() {
    Ints = new List<int>();
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you used "new List<int>(x)" instead of "x.ToList()"?

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use `SelectMany` to get a flatten `List<int>`:

```
public static List<int> FindInts(List<Element> elements)
{
    return elements.SelectMany(e => e.Ints).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

... or aggregating:

```
List<Elements> elements = ... // Populate    
List<int> intsList = elements.Aggregate(Enumerable.Empty<int>(), (ints, elem) => ints.Concat(elem.Ints)).ToList();
```